# Using expect.assertions(x) vs using fail() in jest tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs

I am setting up some asynchronous `junit` typescript tests and it seems I don't understand the documentation correctly.

I wrote a test asking a web API for a specific svg image by sending the ID of the image.

The test sends no ID so the web API should return http code 404. This the test and it works well:

```
test("getSvgByImageId unknown", () => {
    expect.assertions(1);

    return client.getSvgImageById("")
    .then(svg => {
        fail("API should return error")
    })
    .catch(error => {
        expect(error.status).toBe(404);
    })
});
```

But why should I use the expect.assertions(x) when I use the fail() method? The test also works without the expect.assertions(x) line.

Comment: Two documentation pages really helped me: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous and https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-async

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [this post](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2129#issuecomment-454000295) by a `Jest` collaborator in reference to the global `fail()` function:

> That will stop working at some point - it's not part of Jest's documented API.

`Jest` is based on `Jasmine` and `fail()` is a carryover from `Jasmine`.

It is not officially part of the `Jest` documentation so it should not be used as it could be removed from future `Jest` releases.